# Nil object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Could anyone advise me what is wrong on this script? I am a complete beginner with ruby, but I still do not understand why this object is empty in the dump. Thank you for your advice.

```
require 'sinatra'

class Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name, age, country)
    @per_first_name = first_name
    @per_last_name = last_name
    @per_age = age
    @per_country = country
  end

  def get_basic_info()
    puts Array.[](@per_first_name, @per_last_name, @per_age, @per_country)
  end
end

get '/basicInfo' do
  xavier = Person.new('Tada', 'Bada', 25, 'CR')
  xavier.inspect
end
```

[image]

Comment: Which object is `nil`? Please post your error/log output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be an error, i think you are getting a `#` in your page when going to `http://localhost:4567/basicInfo`, and that's the expected behavior since your are calling `inspect` on your new created `Person` object.

I assume that you want to display `get_basic_info` instead, if so, you need to do a couple of changes:

First, remove `puts` from `get_basic_info` since `puts` will print in console, not on your page:

```
def get_basic_info()
  Array.[](@per_first_name, @per_last_name, @per_age, @per_country)
end
```

Second, call your method **before** calling inspect, so you get the array of basic info before inspecting it:

```
get '/basicInfo' do
  xavier = Person.new('Tada', 'Bada', 25, 'CR')
  xavier.get_basic_info.inspect
end
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: @XWizard Glad to help! I will also recommend going through [this](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) guide so get more familiar with Ruby programming style.